# OCFS2 on Ubuntu 18.04 - Missing Kernal Modules

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ocfs2

I am trying to setup OCFS2 on a few servers running Ubuntu 18.04.  I started by installing ocfs2-tools and then setting up things from there.  The issue I cannot solve appears to be the system is missing some kernel modules

```
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com systemd[1]: Starting Load o2cb Modules...
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com o2cb[1533]: checking debugfs...
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com modprobe[1567]: FATAL: Module ocfs2_stackglue not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com modprobe[1575]: FATAL: Module ocfs2_dlmfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com o2cb[1533]: Loading filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs": Unable to load filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs"
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com o2cb[1533]: Failed
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com systemd[1]: o2cb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com systemd[1]: o2cb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 25 08:18:38 xyz.domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Load o2cb Modules.
```

I cannot seem to get past this error. Anyone running OCFS2 on Ubuntu 18.04 have any insights?

Output of apt-file search:

```
sudo apt-file search ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-image-4.15.0-1002-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1002-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1006-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1006-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1008-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1008-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1008-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1008-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1009-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1010-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1010-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1011-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1011-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1012-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1012-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1012-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1012-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1013-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1013-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1015-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1015-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1016-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1016-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1017-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1017-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1018-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1018-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1019-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1020-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1020-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1021-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1021-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1023-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1024-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1024-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1025-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1026-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1026-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1027-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1027-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1028-kvm: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1028-kvm/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1028-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1028-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-1030-oem: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1030-oem/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-20-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-22-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-23-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-24-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-24-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-29-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-30-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-32-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-33-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-34-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-36-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-38-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-38-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-39-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-39-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-42-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.15.0-43-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-4.18.0-13-lowlatency: /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-lowlatency/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1006-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1006-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1007-oracle: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1007-oracle/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1008-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1008-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1009-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1009-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1010-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1010-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1012-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1012-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1013-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1013-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1014-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1014-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1014-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1014-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1015-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1015-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1017-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1018-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1018-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1018-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1018-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1019-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1019-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1021-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1021-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1022-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1022-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1023-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1023-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1024-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1024-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1025-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1025-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1026-gcp: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1028-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1028-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1030-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1030-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1031-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1031-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1032-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1032-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1035-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1035-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-1036-azure: /lib/modules/4.15.0-1036-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-22-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-23-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-24-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-24-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-39-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-42-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-1004-gcp: /lib/modules/4.18.0-1004-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-1005-gcp: /lib/modules/4.18.0-1005-gcp/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-1006-azure: /lib/modules/4.18.0-1006-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-1007-azure: /lib/modules/4.18.0-1007-azure/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-13-generic: /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/fs/ocfs2/dlmfs/ocfs2_dlmfs.ko
```

Comment: could you try to use apt-file search ocfs2_dlmfs.ko ?

Comment: @c4f4t0r I added that output to the original post.  Found quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the kernel modules installed, you need to install the package that match your kernel version:

```
apt install linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic
```

Because in your error you have this `"FATAL: Module ocfs2_stackglue not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic"`

Comment: Bam.  You were correct.  Did that and services started and I was able to add the filesystem.  Thank you!